# Generating html files for AngularJS application with KeystoneJS CMS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, keystonejs

I'm a newbie when it comes to AngularJS and KeystoneJS, and I would really appreciate your help. Thank you guys.

I have done a serving mechanism for my Angular application which uses Express's express.static. At this point, my application can successfully load regular html-files from different locations to a particular page with the code below.

controller.js:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.html = "testing";

    $http({
        url: 'content/content1.html',
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'text'    
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.html = data;
    }).error()

    $scope.message = 'Hello';
});
```

page.html:

```
<div ng-bind="html"></div>
```

routing.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/content'));
```

Next, I would like to load content from a separate KeystoneJS CMS to this particular page in my own Angular application. Basically, I just want to be able to edit some content with KeystoneJS and publish the content on my separate Angular application automatically after that.

1) How can I get the pages exported from Keystone in a form of a html-page?

Comment: This is a VERY broad question. Can you please provide a more narrow use case of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for the update but, again, the question is still extremely broad there are so many possible answers. You could, for example, query the Keystone lists, generate HTML using one of many available tempting languages, and use Express to return it to Angular using a custom route. Or ... you could generate a JSON response, return it with Express, then consume the data in Angular and maybe use directive or some other means to generate the client-side view.

Comment: An example of the first (generating HTML using server-side templates) can be found in https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone-demo. This doesn't use Angular, but the concepts can be extrapolated.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Another question related to this topic. I'm trying to use a link from Keystone in my Angular app which runs in port 3000. I can't get cors on. How can I enable cors in my application? I already tried with this one:

app.all('/api*', keystone.middleware.cors);

Comment: `app.all('/api*', keystone.middleware.cors);` does enable CORS, but only on routes that begin with `/api` (obviously). You need to add the Keystone CORS middleware to every routes to which you will be making cross-origin requests.

Comment: OK got it, works fine now. I would also like to change the URL of a single blog post from mutable title-based URL to a ID-based constant URL. Can you help me how to achieve this?

Comment: There are better places to ask these kind of questions: [keystone gitter](https://gitter.im/keystonejs/keystone), [keystone google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/keystonejs)

Comment: @ikenator, you're getting a bit off topic. I suggest you either edit your question (and add some code) or just add a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I created an AngularJS+KeystoneJS Skeleton starter app which should help you get started if you want to use MEAN with KeystoneJS:

https://github.com/dvdcastro/keystonejs-ng-skeleton

It shows how to have several angularjs projects served using keystone infrastructure. I chose this solution because jade is a very powerful template engine which will allow you to do more with angular.